# Method is undefined - Jasmine

Tags: javascript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm trying a simple test of a method within a file - using Jasmine with Karma:

Test Spec

```
define([
    "water/EventUtils",
    "_Common"
], function(
    EventUtils,
    _Common
) {
    describe("_Common", () => {
        describe('getDatasourceConfigFromId', () => {
            it("makes sure EventUtils method called correctly", () => {
                const queryMethod = spyOn(EventUtils.DataSourceConfigStore, 'query');
                _Common.getDatasourceConfigFromId('123');
                expect(queryMethod).toHaveBeenCalledWith('123');
            });
        });
    });
});
```

This is what I'm testing in _Common.js:

```
getDatasourceConfigFromId: function(ds_id) {
    return EventUtils.DataSourceConfigStore.query({
        id: ds_id
    })[0];
}
```

This is my mocked EventUtils.js

```
define([], function() {
    return {
        DataSourceConfigStore: {
            query: (data) => [data]
        }
    };
});
```

Each time I run the test I get:

> TypeError: EventUtils.DataSourceConfigStore.query(...) is undefined in http://path/to/_Common.js (line 9)

Anyone have ideas why that's undefined?

if I

```
console.log(EventUtils.DataSourceConfigStore.query)
```

it returns

```
(data) => [data]
```

Comment: it probably returns undefined or empty array and you try to reach `0` index of it

Comment: But I have a spy on it so it shouldn't even run `spyOn(EventUtils.DataSourceConfigStore, 'query')`